# Few Dropdownlist values of a webform not getting stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access database

**Table1** with fields (ID(primarykey) AutoNumber, Role Text)

**Table2** with fields (ID(primarykey) AutoNumber, CompanyName Text, Type Text, Fmn Text)

**Table3** with fields (ID(primarykey) AutoNumber, PersNo Text, PersName Text, Company Text, Fmn Text, Role Text)

I have created a form for Table3 where all the fields are text except Company, Fmn and Role which are dropdownlist and these dropdownlist are populated from Table2 from fields CompanyName , Fmn and Table 1 Role.

Now when I submit the form, the query (qryCreateNewUser) gets executed successfully and the data gets entered into database for all the fields of Table3 except the values of two dropdownlist Company,Fmn

```
string qryCreateNewUser = "INSERT INTO tUser (PersNo, PersName, Company , Fmn, Role) VALUES ('" + tbxPersNo.Text.ToString() + "','" + ddlRank.Text.ToString() + "', '" + tbxPersName.Text.ToString() + "','" + ddlUnit.Text.ToString() + "','"+ddlFmn.Text.ToString()+"','"+ddlRole.Text.ToString()+"')";
```

I have tried finding solutions from existing similar kind of issue but couldn’t resolve it.

Html Code:

```
asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnit" runat="server" DataTextField="UnitName" DataValueField="ID"
```

c# Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {

        BindDataSetUnitName();
        //BindDataSetFmn();
    }
}

protected void BindDataSetUnitName() {
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tUnit", connection);
        connection.Open();
        ddlUnit.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
        ddlUnit.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? What value you are getting in `qryCreateNewUser` variable?

Comment: Are you getting any error while running this code,?

Comment: you have to specify `DataTextFiels` and `DataValueField` of `ddl` when you bind `DataSource` to `ddl`

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya, i have debugged the code and was getting the values as desired but was not getting stored in the db, there was also no error shown once the  project was executed

Comment: @FrustatedDeveloper i have specified DataTextFiels and DataValueField of ddl in .aspx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteReader returns a *reader* of the appropriate/specified type, not a DataSource. Try

```
...
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
ddlUnit.DataSource = reader;
ddlUnit.DataBind();
```

Comment: the above solution resolved the problem thanks a ton.